# Create SQL trigger query to dump all column changes into single variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, dynamic, triggers

For some background... I have a collection of tables, and I would like a trigger on each table for `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`. SQL Server version is SQL 2005.

I have an audit table `Audit` that contains a column called `Detail`. My end goal is to create a trigger that will get the list of columns of its table, generate a dynamic select query from either Inserted, Updated, or Deleted, do some string concatenation, and dump that value into the `Detail` column of `Audit`.

This is the process I was thinking:

1. Get columns names in table for `sys.columns`
2. Generate dynamic sql `SELECT` query based on column names
3. Select from `Inserted`
4. foreach row in results, concatenate column values into single variable
5. Insert variable data into `Detail` column

So, the questions:

Is this the best way to accomplish what I'm looking to do? And the somewhat more important question, how do I write this query?

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have - 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008R2? Which edition - Standard, Enterprise? If no less than 2008 Enterprise - did you check CDC (Change Data Captuere)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use FOR XML for this, and just store the results as an XML document.

```
SELECT *
FROM Inserted
FOR XML RAW
```

will give you attibute-centric xml, and

```
SELECT *
FROM Inserted
FOR XML PATH('row')
```

will give you element-centric xml.  Much easier than trying to identify the columns and concatenate them.